# jQuery multiple buttons targeting the same element

Tags: jquery

What I'm looking to do is target a div and populate it with text depending on a button click. There would be say, three buttons, the user clicks the first button, text is populated in the text box below.

Here's my script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#button1').click(function (){
            $('#textbox').empty();
    $('#textbox').prepend('Some text from Button 1');
});
});
</script>
```

Here's what I have so far all together: http://jsfiddle.net/nzTwU/

This is my first question on this site, so if anything is not right, my apologies. I've also never used jsfiddle before so I hope that's right too. If not just let me know.

Right now the first button works fine, I've got it emptying the div first so if you click the button multiple times it doesn't input the same text over and over again. How do I script the same for the other buttons? Do I use an if statement? Is there a better or more appropriate method for what I'm trying to do? Or is what I want to do even possible? I have an extremely rudimentary knowledge of jQuery and I'm unsure how to go about this.

Thanks for any and all advice!

Comment: Simply add another `$("#button2").click(...)` to your code for each button.

Comment: [is this what you want?](http://jsfiddle.net/QLZ9Y/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(document).ready(function (){
$('#button1').click(function (){
            $('#textbox').empty();
    $('#textbox').prepend('Some text from Button 1');
});
  $('#button2').click(function (){
            $('#textbox').empty();
    $('#textbox').prepend('Some text from Button 2');
});
     $('#button3').click(function (){
            $('#textbox').empty();
    $('#textbox').prepend('Some text from Button 3');
});
});
```

here is jsfidle i have edited

http://jsfiddle.net/nzTwU/3/

Comment: Garry that is perfect thank you so much! I was wracking what little knowledge I had and the answer seems pretty simple haha. Thanks again!

Comment: While this works, it is hardly the most efficient or maintainable way to do things. What if you add more buttons?

Answer (score 1):

I would add a class to your buttons in case you don't want all of the buttons in the menu to add text.

Also, unless you want to hard-code an if statement for each textbox in the click event, you could add the unique text to each button using a `data` element:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="buttons">
        <button id="button1" class="addtext" data-text="Some text from button 1">Button 1</button>
    </li>
    <li class="buttons">
        <button id="button2" class="addtext" data-text="Some other text from button 2">Button 2</button>
    </li>
    <li class="buttons">
        <button id="button3" class="addtext" data-text="Even more text from button 3">Button 3</button>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="textbox"></div>
```

That way you can just write one simple function and have the text all ready to go:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.addtext').click(function () {
        $('#textbox').text($(this).data("text"));
    });
});
```

And a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Psnr5/2/) for good measure.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.buttons button').click(function (){
            $('#textbox').empty().prepend('Some text from ' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Use the class you have on your `li`s to apply this to everything. In this test case, we just grab the ID of whatever was clicked and use that for the text.

Since you're looking for the same functionality across multiple similar objects, it's good to abstract your code a bit and base your output on the elements the action occurred on.

http://jsfiddle.net/nzTwU/5/