# I have four buttons and want to return unique text on click of each button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's what I've got for my script. Below it seems to be working fine but it's not working on my site. I've seen other examples where it's suggesting using document.querySelector but I'm not very familiar with Js at all and am having trouble implementing the example scripts. Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong and how I can better write and condense the script? Thanks in advance for your time and help!

```js
document.getElementById("btn").onclick=function () {
        document.getElementById("secdes").innerHTML="change";
   }
    
    document.getElementById("btn1").onclick=function () {
        document.getElementById("secdes").innerHTML="changes";
   }
```

```html
 <div class="col-md-4 buttons btnbox">
                        <button type="button" name="btn" id="btn" class="btn btn-outline-primary homebtn">Home Page</button>
                        <button type="button" name="btn1" id="btn1" class="btn btn-outline-secondary secondarybtn">Secondary Page</button>
                        <button type="button" name="btn2" id="btn2" class="btn btn-outline-secondary blogbtn">Blog</button>
                        <button type="button" name="btn3" id="btn3" class="btn btn-outline-secondary blogbtn">About Page</button>
                        
                        
                        <p class="rubydes">To create the fantasy world for the viewers each illustration incorporated the theme of "The Yellow Brick Road". </p>
                                        
                        <p class="secdes" id="secdes">The challenge of the home page was to seamlessly incorporate the shoe box and "Ruby Slipper" photograph into the illustration.</p>
                       
                       
    
                    
                    </div>
```

Comment: True it seems to be working fine and the code looks right... Do you have your javascript and html in separate files? and if so are sure you're linking it correctly in html: <script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'yourjsfile.js'></script>

Comment: A link to your site would be useful, so that we can see the error. There might be a console error that makes it very plain.

Comment: Yup, two separate files. Other scripts are working just fine.

Comment: Hello Tim, site is not up yet. I'm working locally.

Comment: Also, try this; instead of adding the event listeners in your script, add them manually to the button elements, like so:

<button type="button" name="btn" id="btn" class="btn btn-outline-primary homebtn" onclick="myClickHandler(this)">Home Page</button>

Whether or not that's what you want to do, if it works you'll know the problem has something to do with the way you're adding the event listeners. By passing "this" to the clickHandler function (whatever you call it), you can tell which button was clicked (or you can just pass in anything you want instead of "this").

Comment: Thank you for your insight. Again, I'm very new to javascript/jquery so I'm not really sure what the result is supposed to be but I tried what you've suggested and I didn't  see a change occurring.

 <!---<button type="button" name="btn" id="btn" class="btn btn-outline-primary homebtn">Home Page</button>--->
                        <button type="button" name="btn" id="btn" class="btn btn-outline-primary homebtn" onclick="myClickHandler(this)">Home Page</button>

Comment: I found the answer to what I was trying to achieve here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761071/jquery-multiple-buttons-targeting-the-same-element

Answer (score 2):

Something you could possibly try would be to give each button a unique id and then access them from javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (edited).

Html:

```
<div class="col-md-4 buttons btnbox">
    <button type="button" name="btn" id="btn" class="btn btn-outline-primary homebtn" onclick="myFunction1()">Home Page</button>
    <button type="button" name="btn1" id="btn1" class="btn btn-outline-secondary secondarybtn" onclick="myFunction2()">Secondary Page</button>


    <p class="rubydes">To create the fantasy world for the viewers each illustration incorporated the theme of "The Yellow Brick Road". </p>
    <p class="secdes" id="secdes">The challenge of the home page was to seamlessly incorporate the shoe box and "Ruby Slipper" photograph into the illustration.</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction1(){
     document.getElementById("secdes").innerHTML="change";
}
function myFunction2(){
     document.getElementById("secdes").innerHTML="changes";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! I found what I was looking for here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761071/jquery-multiple-buttons-targeting-the-same-element

Answer (score 1):

Here are a JSFiddle with the solution.

```
    <div class="col-md-4 buttons btnbox">
        <button onclick="javascript:test('text 1', 'secdes')" type="button" name="btn" id="btn" class="btn btn-outline-primary homebtn">Home Page</button>
        <button onclick="javascript:test('text 2', 'secdes')" type="button" name="btn1" id="btn1" class="btn btn-outline-secondary secondarybtn">Secondary Page</button>
        <button onclick="javasxript:test('text 3', 'secdes')" type="button" name="btn2" id="btn2" class="btn btn-outline-secondary blogbtn">Blog</button>
        <button onclick="javascript:test('text 4', 'secdes')" type="button" name="btn3" id="btn3" class="btn btn-outline-secondary blogbtn">About Page</button>
        <p class="rubydes">To create the fantasy world for the viewers each illustration incorporated the theme of "The Yellow Brick Road". </p>

        <p class="secdes" id="secdes">The challenge of the home page was to seamlessly incorporate the shoe box and "Ruby Slipper" photograph into the illustration.</p>
    </div>


    function test(myText, targetID) {
        document.getElementById(targetID).innerHTML=myText;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s8xuajv1/10/

I hope it can help you.

Best regards.